How can I convert PKPass(es) from the PKPassLibrary().passes() and pass it via deep linking to another iOS app?
Objective: I need to pass a PKPass from 1 iOS app to another via deeplinking
The flow goes like this:
I receive a Data from the server, instantiate a PKPass object from it and add it to the wallet. Is there a way to convert the passes retrieved from PKPassLibrary.passes() back into Data so I can base64 encode it and send it via deep link to another app?
Project uses swiftui and passkit

I'd recommend hosting the PKPass on a server, like PassNinja or PassKit does, then just passing that URL from app to app, so the other app can download the PKPass at will.
